# MONGODB-AWS Authentication in SpringBoot Application

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Has anyone used the MONGODB-AWS authentication with SpringBoot?

The MONGODB-AWS authentication is based either on values in environment variables or directly in connection string. Initializing SpringBoot application in this case is easy, but how to update the keys and the token when they expire?

Updating environment variables or configiration bean are things are something that should not be done in Java/SpringBoot. In addition to that all other beans that use the Mongo configuration bean should be also updated.

Is the usage of MONGODB-AWS authentication even supported with SpringBoot and what is the correct way to update the keys and the token?

Answer (score 0):

Use EC2 instance role or ECS task role, the driver will retrieve new credentials every time a connection is created. See [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-authentication/#aws) if the java driver doesn't have equivalent documentation.